# How to find the Proxy Server Address for my connected wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy

I am using my college wifi which requires me to login and authenticate through a web-browser login form.i want to find my server's proxy address and port number to download without logging in.I already used some proxy to download but now the proxy and port number were changed.

plz guide me to find the new proxy address and the port number for windows 8.If any software available please let me know

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to fill out a form to log in, this is known as a "captive portal". It's possible that the system will be set up to allow access to certain sites without logging in, but this would be specific to your system. Consider asking your administrator, or other users. You might also try a search for "captive portal auto login" or similar.